# Trying to add Angular Universal to my app.This error crashes nodemon

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

npm run start causes below problem.
For further information about this problem :: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4386
    fs.js:646
    return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
    ^

```
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/zip2/dist/browser/index.html'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
at Object. (/home/user/zip2/dist/server.js:98:21)
at webpack_require (/home/user/zip2/dist/server.js:20:30)
at /home/satish/Downloads/zip2/dist/server.js:63:18
at Object. (/home/user/zip2/dist/server.js:66:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

Comment: Invalid path ? `D:dist` is not a valid path

Comment: can you see again?

Comment: Did you create browser anf server bundles in dist folder?

Comment: It is created when build process finishes.But it doesn't get created.

Comment: what does your `npm run start script` do exactly?

Comment: "start": "run-p build:dev --APP_THEME=cr-theme1 nodemon",
    "build": "run-s build:client build:aot build:server",
    "build:client": "ng build --prod --app 0",
    "build:aot": "ng build --aot --app 1",
    "build:server": "webpack -p",
    "build:dev": "run-p build:dev:client build:dev:aot build:dev:server",
    "build:dev:client": "ng build -w --aot --app 0",
    "build:dev:aot": "ng build -w --aot --delete-output-path=false --app 1",
    "build:dev:server": "webpack -w",
    "nodemon": "nodemon --watch dist/browser/index.html --watch dist/server.js dist/server.js",

Comment: Maybe you should run tour tasks sequentially instead of in parallel